# I have a problem reguarding datepicker element in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datepicker

when i place a datepicker on my windows form and when it is run , the datepicker displays the default date (current date)
is there anyway to not display date
as i am using it in  a update form, the user may be confused to see dates that havent been selected

i am also using the datepicker in data repeater so is there a way to "not display any date on datepicker"

Comment: search for nullable datetime picker

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/selection/NullableDateTimePicker.aspx